# Can I reverse engineer a pdf file to identify the creator's name?

Tags: digital-forensics, pdf

Here is a quick question. Someone told me that I can reverse engineering a pdf file, extracting and analyzing the underlying XML files, and figure out the creator's name for this pdf.

However, I googled such approach for a while, and cannot figure out a feasible solution. Could anyone shed some light on this point..? Thank you in advance!

Comment: by "creator", do you mean the human author of the document or the program which produced the PDF? please clarify.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky, thank you for your reply. "creator" I mean the author of the document.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky, the "human author"

Comment: There is no underlying XML file per se. You can, however, get at the metadata of the document. Manually, you would do that in Acrobat/Reader and display the document properties. Programmatically, you would look out for a tool which can extract the metadata … I think even ExifTool is capable to get metadata out. However, you will get the author only if there is actually an entry in that according field.

Comment: @MaxWyss I see. Thank you, I tried to open with Acrobat and check the metadata info; however, there is no authorship entry. I guess such information is not embedded in the pdf I am testing. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PDF format is not based on XML but uses a PostScript-inspired dictionary format for its "objects" and streams for other data such as images. There are following  places where document metadata is stored:

- the `/Info` dictionary containing keys such as "Author" , "Producer", "Title" etc.
- the `/Metadata` dictionary which may contain an XML stream with additional information.

Here's an example of retrieving this information using the [low-level PDF parsing tool by Didier Stevens](https://github.com/DidierStevens/DidierStevensSuite/blob/master/pdf-parser.py):

First,  display the "trailer" (something like table of contents of the PDF):

> pdf-parser.py -e t Excite_Project_ZN.pdf

```
trailer
  <<
    /Size 3373
    /Root 1 0 R
    /Info 219 0 R
    /ID [<3572219E83326040B0789EBEAE24A285><3572219E83326040B0789EBEAE24A285>]
  >>

trailer
  <<
    /Size 3373
    /Root 1 0 R
    /Info 219 0 R
    /ID [<3572219E83326040B0789EBEAE24A285><3572219E83326040B0789EBEAE24A285>]
    /Prev 2126182
    /XRefStm 2119246
  >>
```

Now let's check the `/Info` object (number 219):

> pdf-parser.py -o 219 Excite_Project_ZN.pdf

```
obj 219 0
 Type:
 Referencing:

  <<
    /Title ()
    /Author (Alex Matrosov)
    /Keywords (CTPClassification=CTP_PUBLIC:VisualMarkings=)
    /CreationDate "(D:20161121224130-08'00')"
    /ModDate "(D:20161121224130-08'00')"
    /Producer '(\xfe\xff\x00M\x00i\x00c\x00r\x00o\x00s\x00o\x00f\x00t\x00\xae\x00 \x00P\x00o\x00w\x00e\x00r\x00P\x00o\x00i\x00n\x00t\x00\xae\x00 \x002\x000\x001\x006)'
    /Creator '(\xfe\xff\x00M\x00i\x00c\x00r\x00o\x00s\x00o\x00f\x00t\x00\xae\x00\x00P\x00o\x00w\x00e\x00r\x00P\x00o\x00i\x00n\x00t\x00\xae\x00 \x002\x000\x001\x006)'
  >>
```

So here we have the tile and the author. But there is more. If we check the Root object (number 1):

```
>pdf-parser.py -o 1 Excite_Project_ZN.pdf

obj 1 0
 Type: /Catalog
 Referencing: 2 0 R, 220 0 R, 3370 0 R, 3371 0 R

  <<
    /Type /Catalog
    /Pages 2 0 R
    /Lang (en-US)
    /StructTreeRoot 220 0 R
    /MarkInfo
      <<
        /Marked true
      >>
    /Metadata 3370 0 R
    /ViewerPreferences 3371 0 R
  >>
```

We can see the reference to `/Metadata`. Let's check it:

```
>pdf-parser.py -o 3370 Excite_Project_ZN.pdf

obj 3370 0
 Type: /Metadata
 Referencing:
 Contains stream

  <<
    /Type /Metadata
    /Subtype /XML
    /Length 3230
  >>
```

This is a stream which needs to be extracted:

```
>pdf-parser.py -o 3370 -x metadata.xml Excite_Project_ZN.pdf
```

The output is this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xpacket begin="" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta x:xmptk="3.1-701" xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/">
<?xpacket end="w"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
<rdf:Description xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/" rdf:about="">
<pdf:Producer>Microsoft® PowerPoint® 2016</pdf:Producer>
<pdf:Keywords>CTPClassification=CTP_PUBLIC:VisualMarkings=</pdf:Keywords>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
<dc:title>
<rdf:Alt>
<rdf:li xml:lang="x-default"/>
</rdf:Alt>
</dc:title>
<dc:creator>
<rdf:Seq>
<rdf:li>Alex Matrosov</rdf:li>
</rdf:Seq>
</dc:creator>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/">
<xmp:CreatorTool>Microsoft® PowerPoint® 2016</xmp:CreatorTool>
<xmp:CreateDate>2016-11-21T22:41:30-08:00</xmp:CreateDate>
<xmp:ModifyDate>2016-11-21T22:41:30-08:00</xmp:ModifyDate>
</rdf:Description>    

<rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/">    
<xmpMM:DocumentID>uuid:9E217235-3283-4060-B078-9EBEAE24A285</xmpMM:DocumentID>    
<xmpMM:InstanceID>uuid:9E217235-3283-4060-B078-9EBEAE24A285</xmpMM:InstanceID>    
</rdf:Description>    
</rdf:RDF>

</x:xmpmeta>
```

Comment: Thank you Igor, this is exactly what I am looking for. Fantastic.

Comment: When I run `pdf-parser.py -o <metadataobj> -x metadata.xml Excite_Project_ZN.pdf ` I get nothing =/ despite having a stream length of `/Length 1134`

Comment: for me `-x` is **extract malformed content** I had to use `-d metadata.xml` for dump. Which worked fine.. You may want to [edit] and update unless you're sure you meant `-x`. Alternatively I can just write it out the screen with `-c`.